# Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string | ArrayBuffer'. Property 'split' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, typescript, split, base64, angular7

"I want to split a base64Audio.Want to remove this - text.data:audio/wav;base64,So what will be the proper code "

“This is for Angular 7 .”

```js
 const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(data.blob);
    let base64Audio ;
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      const base64data = reader.result;
      console.log(base64data);

     base64Audio = base64data.split(' , ')[1];
      console.log(base64Audio);
```

" I expect the output should be only splitted text "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(data.blob);
let base64Audio ;
reader.onloadend = function() {
const base64data = reader.result as string;
console.log(base64data);
base64Audio = base64data.replace("data:audio/wav;base64,", "");
console.log(base64Audio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .slice() before using .split():

```
this.urlPath = this.urlpath.slice(0, 34);
```

This will help you get the required one and remove the unwanted and then try to get the required array from the sliced part and then from there try to get the splitted one.

```
this.urlname = this.response.responseList[0].FileName;
this.urlname = this.urlname.split(".", 1);
```

*this is the typescript example where i used slice before split as i was also getting the same error...*
Full Example link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jyjs3v